# Slowing down in MySQL insertion with 3 indexes and 1 foreign key

Tags: mysql, bulk-insert

I was working on a MySQL database using Innodb with billions of lines of data.

My table got 16 fields, 3 indexes, 1 foreign key, and 1 primary key. My buffer pool size is 47 GiB.

When I tested inserting 10 million lines with indexes disabled, it took 100s.

When indexes are enabled, as I was continuously inserting billions of lines in chunks of 10 million lines, it initially took 150s...then went up 400s...then to 1000s...and now it went up to 2000s per 10 million lines (using load data statement).

I want to know how to speed up my insertion with these indexes that are necessary for later use.

MySQL crashes a couple times during the insertion and I have to restart it...I wonder if the slow down is correlated to the crashes. Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE` is more descriptive than `DESCRIBE`.  Which table are you worried about?  What are the `SELECTs` that need the indexes?  Are any of the indexes "composite"?

Comment: The only table that is gonna be super huge is `transitions`, the one with hundreds of billions of rows. I updated with show create table. I already dropped the indexes for inserting, as you suggest, and none of the indexes are composite.

Answer (score 0):

1. disable keys and FKs
2. load the billions
3. enable

Meanwhile, provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; there are likely to be some critiques that may help.

In particular, if this is a Data Warehouse application, do you have any summary tables?

Comment: if we disable the keys before insertion, isn't enabling the keys after having a huge table gonna take forever though?

Comment: It is likely to be faster to recreate an index all at once, than to incrementally add one new entry at a time.  Step 3 rebuilds the index(es) all at once.

Comment: I will disable them. Thx! And I updated the tables, maybe you will have some advice on my table design?

Answer (score -1):

Do the following before you loading the table

```
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=1;
SET autocommit=0;
SET unique_checks=0;
SET foreign_key_checks=0;
```

Once the import has been completed, enable all.

Use multiple-row insert [like in mysqldump --extended-insert]